# BigInt or Varchar for a large number I won't ever sort / calculate on

Tags: mysql, myisam

I need to store users' Facebook IDs in a column in my DB.

The ID always consists of only digits, and can be as large as a number in excess of 500 million. Considering that I won't ever need to do any arithmetic, sorting or use relational operators on the values, what would be a better choice: `BigInt` or `varchar` ?

The value will always be unique and never non-existent (`null`)

The only operation I do is check for the existence of an ID in the database, i.e. the `=` operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

varchar adds overhead:

- length of the string needs stored (extra 2 bytes IIRC in MySQL) per field *and* in the index
- requires more processing for collation on comparison

Saying that, what does the Facebook API describe the type as? Use the "native" one of course

Comment: The JSON encoded response from the Facebook API does not suggest any type. Here is an example: https://graph.facebook.com/ayushsobti

Comment: I see in [http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) : "Fields. The User object has the following fields:" `Name: id | Description: The user's Facebook ID | Permissions: No access_token required | Returns: **string**`

Answer (score 1):

According to the [**MySQL Documentation on BIGINT**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-type-overview.html)

> BIGINT[(M)] [UNSIGNED] [ZEROFILL]   A large integer. The signed range
>   is -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807. The unsigned range is
>   0 to 18446744073709551615.
>
> SERIAL is an alias for BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE.
>
> Some things you should be aware of with respect to BIGINT columns:
>
> ■  All arithmetic is done using signed BIGINT or DOUBLE values, so you
>   should not use unsigned big integers larger than 9223372036854775807
>   (63 bits) except with bit functions! If you do that, some of the last
>   digits in the result may be wrong because of rounding errors when
>   converting a BIGINT value to a DOUBLE.
>
> MySQL can handle BIGINT in the following cases:
>
> ◦  When using integers to store large unsigned values in a BIGINT
>   column.
>
> ◦  In MIN(col_name) or MAX(col_name), where col_name refers to a
>   BIGINT column.
>
> ◦  When using operators (+, -, *, and so on) where both operands are
>   integers.
>
> ■  You can always store an exact integer value in a BIGINT column by
>   storing it using a string. In this case, MySQL performs a
>   string-to-number conversion that involves no intermediate
>   double-precision representation.
>
> ■  The -, +, and * operators use BIGINT arithmetic when both operands
>   are integer values. This means that if you multiply two big integers
>   (or results from functions that return integers), you may get
>   unexpected results when the result is larger than 9223372036854775807.

As you stated, as long as you do not do any arithmetic, sorting or use relational operators on the values, I would go with BIGINT.

The documentation just mentioned storing the number as a string to bypass intermediate steps done through double precision representation.